# curl: (56) Recv failure node.js on virtualbox

Tags: node.js, curl, virtualbox

I have installed **node.js** on a virtual-box machine. I started the webserver example from nodejs.org, curl-ed from the virtual machine and got "hello world".
 then i forwarded `port 8000` on the host to the example-port on the guest. when i curl the forwarded port on the guest i get:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I will point you to a question asked on superuser. http://superuser.com/questions/448941/accessing-ubuntu-guest-virtualbox-node-js-server-from-windows-host